# Dual display fails after login

Tags: manjaro

I have installed Manjaro Mate edition on my desktop with dual display. Both displays were working fine until I recently did a pacman -Syyu. Thereafter when the login screen appears both displays are working fine. As soon as I login my second display disappears (i.e it is all black). When I logout the second display works again.

I have googled but could not find anything useful to fix the issue. See below for output of journalctl -f when I login

All help greatly appreciated

```
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle lightdm[5057]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle lightdm[5057]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd[1]: session-c12.scope: Killing process 5005 (lightdm) with signal SIGTERM.
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd[1]: session-c12.scope: Killing process 5017 (slick-greeter) with signal SIGTERM.
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd[1]: Stopping Session c12 of user lightdm.
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle lightdm[5005]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd[1]: session-c12.scope: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd[1]: Stopped Session c12 of user lightdm.
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd-logind[342]: Removed session c12.
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle lightdm[5057]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lk by (uid=0)
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd-logind[342]: New session c13 of user lk.
Apr 20 10:51:50 pickle systemd[1]: Started Session c13 of user lk.
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle lightdm[375]: Error opening audit socket: Protocol not supported
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=5071 comm="mate-session ")
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle systemd[734]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.5' (uid=1000 pid=5071 comm="mate-session ")
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle systemd[734]: Started Accessibility services bus.
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle at-spi-bus-launcher[5091]: dbus-daemon[5097]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=5071 comm="mate-session ")
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=5071 comm="mate-session ")
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle at-spi-bus-launcher[5091]: dbus-daemon[5097]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle at-spi-bus-launcher[5091]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Apr 20 10:51:51 pickle mate-session[5071]: WARNING: Unable to find provider '' of required component 'dock'
Apr 20 10:51:52 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.1084' (uid=1000 pid=5110 comm="/usr/lib/mate-settings-daemon/mate-settings-daemon")
Apr 20 10:51:52 pickle systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr 20 10:51:52 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.mate.panel.applet.BriskMenuFactory' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=5130 comm="mate-panel ")
Apr 20 10:51:52 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=5130 comm="mate-panel ")
Apr 20 10:51:52 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.mate.panel.applet.ClockAppletFactory' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=5130 comm="mate-panel ")
Apr 20 10:51:52 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.mate.panel.applet.NotificationAreaAppletFactory' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=5130 comm="mate-panel ")
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.mate.panel.applet.ClockAppletFactory'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.mate.panel.applet.NotificationAreaAppletFactory'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle gnome-keyring-daemon[5068]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Activating service name='org.mate.SettingsDaemon.DateTimeMechanism' requested by ':1.1087' (uid=1000 pid=5145 comm="/usr/lib/mate-panel/clock-applet ") (using servicehelper)
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.mate.SettingsDaemon.DateTimeMechanism'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle clock-applet[5145]: Negative content width -9 (allocation 1, extents 5x5) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.mate.panel.applet.BriskMenuFactory'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle gnome-keyring-daemon[5068]: The SSH agent was already initialized
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle gnome-keyring-daemon[5068]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=5134 comm="caja ")
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle polkitd[386]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c13 (system bus name :1.1093 [/usr/lib/mate-polkit/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/mate/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle brisk-menu[5137]: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle brisk-menu[5137]: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle brisk-menu[5137]: Negative content width -19 (allocation 1, extents 10x10) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle brisk-menu[5137]: Negative content height -9 (allocation 1, extents 5x5) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[734]: Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle msm_notifier[5191]: qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.mate.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1.18' (uid=1000 pid=5137 comm="/usr/libexec/brisk-menu ")
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=5134 comm="caja ")
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[734]: Started Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=5134 comm="caja ")
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle gvfs-afc-volume-monitor[5231]: Volume monitor alive
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[734]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=5134 comm="caja ")
Apr 20 10:51:53 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[734]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle msm_notifier[5191]: qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: yes
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.mate.ScreenSaver'
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle NetworkManager[346]: <info>  [1555782714.3225] agent-manager: req[0x560c11d74ef0, :1.1097/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle mate-screensave[5217]: screensaver already running in this session
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.19' (uid=1000 pid=5169 comm="nm-applet ")
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5' unit='evolution-source-registry.service' requested by ':1.38' (uid=1000 pid=5196 comm="/usr/lib/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-not")
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Evolution source registry...
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.manjaro.pamac.system' unit='pamac-system.service' requested by ':1.1121' (uid=1000 pid=5182 comm="pamac-tray ")
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[1]: Starting Pamac System Session...
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.manjaro.pamac.system'
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[1]: Started Pamac System Session.
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.1123' (uid=1000 pid=5168 comm="python /usr/bin/blueman-applet ")
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[1]: pamac-system.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.gnome.OnlineAccounts' requested by ':1.42' (uid=1000 pid=5264 comm="/usr/lib/evolution-source-registry ")
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5'
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[734]: Started Evolution source registry.
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle goa-daemon[5276]: goa-daemon version 3.32.0 starting
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating service name='org.gnome.Identity' requested by ':1.43' (uid=1000 pid=5276 comm="/usr/lib/goa-daemon ")
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.OnlineAccounts'
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Identity'
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7' unit='evolution-calendar-factory.service' requested by ':1.38' (uid=1000 pid=5196 comm="/usr/lib/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-not")
Apr 20 10:51:54 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Evolution calendar service...
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7'
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle systemd[734]: Started Evolution calendar service.
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9' unit='evolution-addressbook-factory.service' requested by ':1.45' (uid=1000 pid=5288 comm="/usr/lib/evolution-calendar-factory ")
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Evolution address book service...
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9'
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle systemd[734]: Started Evolution address book service.
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=5134 comm="caja ")
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle systemd[734]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle dbus-daemon[4999]: [session uid=1000 pid=4999] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Apr 20 10:51:55 pickle systemd[734]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 620...
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped target Default.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[734]: run-user-620-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: run-user-620-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: run-user-620-gvfs.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: dbus.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: gvfs-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: at-spi-dbus-bus.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: gvfs-daemon.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped target Basic System.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped target Paths.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped target Sockets.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: gpg-agent-browser.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: gpg-agent-ssh.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed Sound System.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: gpg-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: gpg-agent-extra.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: dirmngr.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: p11-kit-server.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed p11-kit server.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Stopped target Timers.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: dbus.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Reached target Shutdown.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Started Exit the Session.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5009]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[5011]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user lightdm
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: user@620.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 620.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/620...
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[734]: run-user-620.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: run-user-620.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@620.service: Succeeded.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/620.
Apr 20 10:52:01 pickle systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 620.
Apr 20 10:52:19 pickle dbus-daemon[344]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Apr 20 10:52:23 pickle systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been havibg similar problems with multiple distros.
Could If anyone is is having the same issue it's most likely due to a lightdm bug.
You can try switching to gdm3 like so:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

If it's not installed then go ahead and install it first.

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gdm3